# need Delete action for zend framework using my sql

Tags: zend-framework

I need to pass an id value from phtml to mastercontroller.  Also, from master controller to mapper to delete a specific row, if I click that delete icon.

Comment: @Todd: [Please remove "please" and "thanks" and so forth when editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). (You don't have to edit just to do that, unless it's gratuitous -- but I edited specifically to remove that bold "please help". :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the id in the view file i.e. phtml ? If yes then in your view,

```
$fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$baseUrl = $fc->getBaseUrl();
echo '<a href="'.$baseurl. '/'.'master/delete/id/'.$id.'">Delete</a>';
```

Here in url (under href) master = controller and delete = action and $id is the id value that you have in phtml file. Onclicking the link this will send a request to delete controller in delete controller you will have to get the id passed

```
deleteAction(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $modelObj = new Model_Mymodel();
    $where = array('primary_id =?'=> $id);
    $modelObj->delete($where);
}
```

Your model Model_Mymodel should extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, hence delete function with given where condition will delete the row.

I hope this was clear and simple enough.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Rohan . I will try to Get the Output

Comment: did it work? If yes its good to accept the answer rather than leaving it as unanswered

Comment: i tried out but error only came..The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Comment: If error says url not found then it probably is the reason :) Just for your information since ur new to zend by default zend urls look something like: localhost/myproject/public/master/list [here master is a controller class i.e. (MasterController) and list is action (listAction). If you debug the url $baseUrl should give you upto public and rest is what you want to give. Do you have modules in the directory structure (could be default). Could you post the name of your controllerClass and action. Solution is quite simple and does work on my machine so u might need to find what bug you made

Comment: controller name is mastercontroller.inside master controller deleteuniversityaction is the action name.i have some other task.yeaterday what i asked my team mates finished.now other task for me.if i click the university,fetching data from database table wil be display.so i can assume the row to delete myself and i want to delete that particular row manually in coding.can u help me out in this dont mind.

Comment: i tried myself i got the output for my second question thank you